# How to read a JSON file and then send via curl as HTTP POST in Unix Shell Script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, curl

Am trying to read a JSON file from a Unix Shell Script (am inside the same dir as `product.json`) and send it using `curl`.

`curlProduct.sh`:

```
for file in ~/work/project/json/product.json

do 
  echo "$file"
   curl -X POST --data @"$file" 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/purchaseProduct' \
   --header 'Content-Type:application/json' \ 
   --header 'Authorization: Bearer f682e27f-daf6-234r-3456-623b9fe65bds'

  echo "After HTTP POST"  
done
```

---

When I run this using:

`sh curlProduct.sh`

The only thing it does is print the fully qualified file path (along with name) seems to be hung at this line `echo "$file"`, forcing me to to issue a `control-c` to cancel, every time:

`/Users/pnwlover/work/project/json/product.json`

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Is there something listening on localhost:8080? Is there a firewall in the way that's dropping traffic? If you have `netcat` installed, what does `nc -vvv localhost 8080` do?

Comment: @roaima - `Connection to localhost port 8080 [tcp/http-alt] succeeded!` using `netcat` along with command you suggested.

Comment: That's great. Pleased to see you've got a solution. Next time it would be better to add information (i.e. responses to requests for clarification) to your question so that others can find it easily.

Answer (score -1):

Got it working like this by rearranging the `curl` args, as follows:

```
  curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer 20fa6074-4478-47d3-ds6c-b87be44bd74c' \
    --data @"$file" 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/purchaseProduct';
```

Comment: I doubt it was the ordering of the argument, but possibly the changed authorization header?